# Visual Studio 2013 - Oracle.DataAccess File "cannot be found"

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2013

I am experiencing a weird problem. I downloaded and installed the latest version of Oracle's ODAC plug-in for Visual Studio. After that, I added Oracle.DataAccess to my project's references, added in the "using" statements for it, then ran the program. At the start of runtime, I get this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't quite understand what is causing this error to occur.

Comment: I think the key might be in the "or one of its dependencies".

Comment: Either way, I would suggest you could try SysInternals Process Monitor (it's free) to see what it's looking for.

Comment: Do you have an Oracle client installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use simply the newest version of ODAC.

The architecture (i.e. 32 bit or 64 bit) of ODAC has to match your installed Oracle Client. Both also have to match your target architecture in compiler settings.

For ODAC Version 4.121.x you must have Oracle Client version 12.1 installed.

Your compiler target .NET Framework has to be Version 4 (or higher)

This all does not apply if you use the ODP.NET Managed Driver, there you simply use and copy the single DLL `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`

Comment: I am now getting this "ORA-12541: TNS: No listener" error after switching to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess when I attempt to open my connection.

Comment: Then your ODAC seems to work. However, your database is not found. I recomment to open a new question for this.